# Why would a CSS file be imported into typescript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

In an older, complex code base that uses Angular 4 with a custom Webpack, there were some components that imported a css file, in the same way that you would import a module for a side effect. An example (this is the complete file, with different variable names):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import '../../assets/css/styles.css';

@Component({
    selector: 'sidebar-app',
    templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

styles.css

```
.content_body {
    padding: 0;
}

.basic_page_wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I have never seen css being imported in typescript, and all other examples I've found use the styles in some way, for example

`import * as s from './Button.css';`

Why would a css file be imported like `import '../../assets/css/styles.css';` inside an angular component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using bundlers such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/), one might import a CSS file in order to process it and pack it into the same bundle as the JavaScript module that imports it.

In webpack, this is done using the [`style-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/). Read more in [this medium post](https://medium.com/a-beginners-guide-for-webpack-2/webpack-loaders-css-and-sass-2cc0079b5b3a)!